# How can I give initial focus to the edit field using GetSaveFileName?

Tags: c++, flutter, winapi

I am working on a Flutter AP, and I use [FilePicker](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker) to handle browse file. When opening dialog, I can't directly type on edit field before clicking it,
I found the OPENFILENAMEW setting in source code, but it seems no option to give focus. How to give initial focus to edit field?

[Full source code](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/blob/master/lib/src/windows/file_picker_windows.dart)

```
Pointer<OPENFILENAMEW> _instantiateOpenFileNameW({
   bool allowMultiple = false,
   String? dialogTitle,
   String? defaultFileName,
   String? initialDirectory,
   List<String>? allowedExtensions,
   FileType type = FileType.any,
   bool lockParentWindow = false,
}) {
    final lpstrFileBufferSize = 8192 * maximumPathLength;
    final Pointer<OPENFILENAMEW> openFileNameW = calloc<OPENFILENAMEW>();

    openFileNameW.ref.lStructSize = sizeOf<OPENFILENAMEW>();
    openFileNameW.ref.lpstrTitle = (dialogTitle ?? defaultDialogTitle).toNativeUtf16();
    openFileNameW.ref.lpstrFile = calloc.allocate<Utf16>(lpstrFileBufferSize);
    openFileNameW.ref.lpstrFilter = fileTypeToFileFilter(type, allowedExtensions).toNativeUtf16();
    openFileNameW.ref.nMaxFile = lpstrFileBufferSize;
    openFileNameW.ref.lpstrInitialDir = (initialDirectory ?? '').toNativeUtf16();
    openFileNameW.ref.flags = ofnExplorer | ofnFileMustExist | ofnHideReadOnly;

    if (lockParentWindow) {
      openFileNameW.ref.hwndOwner = _getWindowHandle();
    }

    if (allowMultiple) {
      openFileNameW.ref.flags |= ofnAllowMultiSelect;
    }

    if (defaultFileName != null) {
      validateFileName(defaultFileName);

      final Uint16List nativeString = openFileNameW.ref.lpstrFile.cast<Uint16>  ().asTypedList(maximumPathLength);
      final safeName = defaultFileName.substring(0,min(maximumPathLength - 1, defaultFileName.length),);
      final units = safeName.codeUnits;
      nativeString.setRange(0, units.length, units);
      nativeString[units.length] = 0;
    }

    return openFileNameW;
  }
```

Update: I found if set lockParentWindow=true, it would happen, if set false, it's fine.

```
FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath(lockParentWindow: false);
```

What exactly does hwndOwner do? It is set to the hwnd of the main window and locks it, but I think it does something else?

Comment: `Get(Open|Save)FileName()` have an option to specify a callback function that is called during dialog initialization and notified of actions within the dialog. You can use that to manually move focus to the desired edit field when the dialog is initialized. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/open-and-save-as-dialog-boxes

Comment: I cannot reproduce with the [fileisinuse](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/7cbd99ac1d2b4a0beffbaba29ea63d024ceff700/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/fileisinuse/fileisinusesample.cpp#L472) sample whether [hwndOwner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamea) is set or not.

Comment: I found that if I set other Ap like Notepad, it's fine, but not flutter Ap, and it's 100% happen in file picker v5.2.5 and randomly happen in v5.3.2

Comment: I also try hook function but can't get the hwnd of the dialog (only get flutter ap and it's caption windows), so can't set focus to it.